# How to append specific indices of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

If I have a matrix:

`x <- matrix(c(0), ncol=2, nrow=2)`

```
x
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    0
```

and I want to change `x[,2][2]` to a 1 instead of a 0 and save that in a new matrix `y` so that the output would be:

```
y
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    0
[2,]    0    1
```

how do I do this in R?

Comment: Without modifying the `x`, one option may be `x + ((2*col(x)- row(x))==2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the original matrix, you could reverse the order of the operations that you want to perform, meaning that you first store a copy of the matrix `x` in a new variable `y` and then manipulate the entries of the matrix `y`.

```
y <- x
y[2,2] <- 1
```

Else, if you really want to change `x` and afterwards store a copy of the modified matrix in `y`... well, I guess that the changes are rather obvious: that would be `x[2,2] <-1` followed by `y <- x`.

Comment: Glad I could help  ;-) By the way, I think that being slow is sometimes a virtue.